# Imprimir imagenes de un richtextbox

Tags: c#, windows-forms, imagen, print, richtextbox

Tengo un richtextbox el cual contiene los codigos de barra que se van generando.
Todos se muestran en dicho control.
Al finalizar se desea imprimir dicho contenido usando el siguiente codigo:

```
 PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
 printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custum", 500, 500);
 printDocument1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.PrintDocument_PrintPage);
 PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog1 = new PrintPreviewDialog();
 printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;                   
 printDocument1.Print();

private void PrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{            
   e.Graphics.DrawString(richTextBox1.Text, new Font("Arial",12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 100, 100);
}
```

Pero no imprime nada, ninguna imagen.

Alguna ayuda?

Gracias mil

Comment: Puedes usar simplemente `PrintDocument_PrintPage` en lugar de `new PrintPageEventHandler(this.PrintDocument_PrintPage)`.

Comment: El codigo de barras, estas seguro que es una imagen, y no un tipo de fuente???

Comment: Es una imagen tipo jpg.  Voy a tratar con PrintDocument_PrintPage.  Les aviso.